# Attach a sql column value to the file name of a file that was written from another columns contents obtained from the same dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a dataset returned from one table with 3 columns; `study_key`, `version` and `interp_text_rtf`.

I write the `interp_text_rtf` to a file and need to attach the version value (an int between 1 and 9 depending on how many versions)to the file name created from the `interp_text_rtf` contents.

I have this code so far:

```
public void WriteRTF(DataSet aDataSet)
{
        foreach (DataTable aDataTable in aDataSet.Tables)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < aDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (DataColumn wDataColumn  in aDataTable.Columns)
                {
                    if (wDataColumn.ColumnName == "interpretation_text_rtf")
                    {
                        rtf = aDataTable.Rows[i][wDataColumn].ToString();

                    }
                }

                File.WriteAllText(mPath + rtfFile + i + ".rtf", rtf);
            }
        }  
}
```

Right now it is just incrementing "i" with 0, 1, 2 etc depending on how many versions but I need to use value from version column instead of increment.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you iterating the columns?
You can access them directly using the column name:

```
foreach (DataTable aDataTable in aDataSet.Tables)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < aDataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
          rtf = aDataTable.Rows[i]["interpretation_text_rtf"].ToString();
          version = aDataTable.Rows[i]["version"].ToString();
          File.WriteAllText(mPath + rtfFile + i + version +".rtf", rtf);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a pile @Zohar Peled...I am a student learning and this site is the best!!! Thanks again!